# Windows randomly drops half of connection

Tags: windows, networking, router

Using Windows 7 Home Premium or Windows 10 with an 10/100 Onboard Nvidia Ethernet controller, Cat5 Ethernet cable, and  AT&T router/modem combo (on a known good port); randomly, I will lose half of the connectivity to my machine.  That is, I can ping out, but not ping in from anywhere.  What could be causing this problem?  It seems to happen when I'm not using the machine or have let it idle for a long time.

This machine is using a static IP (192.168.1.59), as are all the other machines on this network.

From any other machine:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.59

PING 192.168.1.59 (192.168.1.59): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
...
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2902
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2903
^C
--- 192.168.1.59 ping statistics ---
2905 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

Disabling then Re-enabling the Ethernet controller solves the issue, at least temporarily. It happens regardless of activity.

Output of `ping 192.168.1.59` and `arp -a`:

```
Pauls-Mac-mini:~ esmith$ ping 192.168.1.59
PING 192.168.1.59 (192.168.1.59): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
^C
--- 192.168.1.59 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
Pauls-Mac-mini:~ esmith$ arp -a 
? (192.168.1.59) at 0:17:31:61:1:bb on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.254) at 78:96:84:8a:8:f0 on en1 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.199.1) at 6c:70:9f:d4:8c:1e on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

MAJOR UPDATE: DHCP does drop the connection.

EVEN MAJORER UPDATE: It just happened with a PCI ethernet card (non-Nvidia).  Is something wrong with my OS, or what?

Ok, new update:  Windows 10 started having instability issues (random hard reboots) so I formatted and went back to a clean install of Windows 7 Home Premium.  I'm running on the PCI ethernet card (Realtek chipset) and it is still dropping the connection.  I'm completely stumped...  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No answers?  Any suggestions?  Anything at all?

Comment: You need to troubleshoot. Find out how far you get in the process. Does an ARP request get sent? Does an ARP reply get received? Does the ping request go out? Does it get received? Is a ping reply sent?

Comment: How do I test for those? @DavidSchwartz

Comment: You can use any troubleshooting procedure you want. There's no "one right way" to do it. You can start with `arp -av` to see the ARP table.

Comment: See edit to question for output @DavidSchwartz, I'm not familiar with this tool and its uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was snooping around on the internet as well and found that it could be related to your static IP. Is it a possibility to change your IP address to obtain automatically? Even if this is not a long-term option, perhaps you could try and see if this can resolve your issue temporarily.

How:

- go to network and sharing center -> local area connection -> properties
- click IPv6 or IPv4 (dependent on which one you are using)
- click obtain IP address automatically

One other option I had in mind (though this may not be possible depending on your ethernet drivers):

- go to network and sharing center-> local area connection -> properties -> configure (client for Microsoft services) -> advanced.
- In my case, there's a list there which lets you select various different options.
- Select the option interrupt moderation and disable it.

Hope any of these options work. I do agree with Journeyman though that buying a cheap PCI-e network card is probably a good option.

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I can.  How would the static IP throw it off?  It's a 100% free IP.

Comment: I disabled Interrupt Moderation, and I'll let you know tomorrow if it holds up.

Comment: So far it seems to be working...Will update in the morning

Comment: I must admit I don't know why the static ip would be an issue, but I remember it solving one of my issues at some point as well. Look forward to your update.

Comment: Disabling Interrupt Moderation didn't fix it, it just went down.  Will try the dynamic IP tomorrow.

Comment: For the last couple hours, DHCP has held up.  Will update in an hour or three.

Comment: ok...3 hours and DHCP hasn't dropped...

Comment: Sounds good. If it still hasn't tomorrow it sounds like you have your solve.

Comment: Why would a static IP cause that though?

Comment: Because I really prefer an IP that I can stick to, since I use this machine as a server quite often.

Comment: Are you in any position to change anything in the router? Are you 100% sure that no other computer tries to get the same ip address? Did you already test changing the static ip address to another static ip address?

Comment: If you use Dropbox or something, you could make a small script that executes every time you start and saves the ip in a file. This is of course not as convenient as a static ip, but still more convenient than internet problems, so could at least be a good temporary fix.

Comment: Well, this is on a LAN only network, so I don't have internet, just intranet.  Is there a way to disable and enable the network interface from the command line do you know?

Comment: Or maybe that need to be a different Q

Comment: This might work: Start elevated Command Prompt.

Get NIC list and index number:
wmic nic get name, index

Enable NIC with index number: (eg: 7)
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call enable

Disable NIC with index number: (eg: 7)
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable. Though indeed, it makes sense to make this a separate question if you need it. Furthermore, you could try choosing an IP address outside the DHCP range of the router, this might help. Otherwise, can you change router settings? If you can't it isn't useful to think about that.

Comment: Yeah, I've been using an IP outside the DHCP range, and yes I have 100% admin access to the router, but it's a crummy AT&T router, so you can't reserve DHCP addresses.  If you have any other ideas let me know, since I'd love to have this working.

Comment: Here's the link to the new question: http://superuser.com/questions/1002880/how-to-enable-disable-ethernet-controller-from-command-line

Comment: And thanks for your help, you gave me (at a minimum) a functional system.

Comment: MAJOR UPDATE @BramMooij  :  DHCP just dropped the connection!!  Any ideas?

Comment: That's very unfortunate. I don't have time to immediately look into it, but I'll do my best to figure it out later on. I'll get back to you. Have you got the option to try Linux or something else temporarily? It could also be a hardware issue, in which case the problem should persist after changing to another OS. I recently had a network card that always worked for a while after disabling and re-enabling, replacing it with a very similar module fixed it. If that's the case then you should definitely just buy a PCI (-e) network card.

Comment: You could also try safe mode, that should give a somewhat similar test to trying Linux, getting rid of a lot of possibly interfering third party programmes and such.

Comment: I used to have Windows XP Pro on this machine, and it never failed with that.  I also had Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04, and it never failed with either one of those.

Comment: Did the problem start immediately after going to windows 7? Or after a few months, years?

Comment: I believe it was immediately after I went to Windows 7.  It may have started later, but I wasn't using that NIC until a few months after, but I did notice the problem as soon as I started using it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31884/discussion-between-brammooij-and-daniel).

Comment: See edit to question

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its a known issue [(though in windows 7)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/979464), and windows 10 ought to  have the same network stack.

Try turning off receive side scaling. Open a administrative command prompt (I like to use <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> - <kbd>x</kbd> to open the magic console) and type in `netsh interface tcp set global rss=disabled`. See if that helps.

Sounds like its an older machine, and nvidia NICs and chipsets are somewhat well known for being flaky. I'd consider the 20 quid or so to get a pci or pci-e network card.

Comment: So if I disable RSS and it works, will there be a major performance degradation?

Comment: Trivially slightly higher processor load in theory. And of course, you can re-enable it easily. Its probably one of the simpler things to try when troubleshooting something like this.

Comment: I'll try this in the morning.  If it works you get the +50 as well (as if you needed it with 81+k...)

Comment: Its just imaginary internet points. I typically give away any rep I get in bounties (and at the moment a bit more actually) to stuff that interests me, or great answers. Its more the warm fuzzy feeling of remembering and finding an obscure factoid ;)

Comment: OK, so I ran that command about 3 hours ago and it just dropped now.