# How to enable/disable ethernet controller from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, ethernet

How do I disable then re-enable (effectively a power cycle) the Ethernet controller on my Windows 10 Home PC?  I am having an issue which requires the controller to be reset every once and a while.

Comment: Please see this question as well: http://superuser.com/questions/1002902/how-to-detect-bi-directional-link-state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start elevated Command Prompt.

Get NIC list and index number:
wmic nic get name, index

Enable NIC with index number: (eg: 7)
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call enable

Disable NIC with index number: (eg: 7)
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable

Comment: Thanks.  That worked well when I figured out how to spell 'adapter' right.